# On a grid, where does the vision of a creature originate from?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, battle-map, line-of-sight

Where does the vision of a creature originate from on a grid?

For large or taller creatures, does vision originate from all of the space it occupies?

What about height - can a creature see at all height levels at once?

For example, if a Halfling is within 5 feet of a Cloud Giant and the giant casts the Fog Cloud spell in a way that places the bottom of the fog 5 feet off the ground - the Halfling can see the giant's heel below the fog and attack it without occurring disadvantage. Can the giant see the Halfling, though? Does the giant have a line of sight to the Halfling? The giant's head is above the Fog Cloud, and so it can't see the Halfling from up there, but there is no obstruction from the bottom of its space to the Halfling.

Comment: Do you consider having "vision" and having "line of sight" two different things? Or are they equivalent?

Comment: @WillemRenzema I'm not sure, are they the same or different? If they are different, I would like an answer to both.

Comment: Your question is kinda all over the place. Where vision originates on a grid has nothing to do with seeing straight down through a _fog cloud_.

Comment: @mivascott if the sight originates from the eyes they can't see, of it originates from everywhere that would include the feet, and they would see the halfling clearly

Comment: I assume you are looking for a strict 'RAW says' answer, because otherwise this is pretty obvious?

Comment: A *Fog Cloud* is a sphere of 20ft radius, hence even if it is cast 5 feet above the ground it covers the feet of the Giant, unless they stay close to the boundary of such sphere.

Comment: Something else to consider would be Blightsight. That would qualify as @SeriousBri suggested as "vision" from the feet.

Answer (score 1):

Vision originates from the character's eyes. It's up to the DM to judge what is reasonable. Your ruling seems reasonable to me, I don't see why a halfling that is under the fog can't attack a giant's foot which is also under the fog. Since the halfling is not trying to see something in the fog there's no source of disadvantage.

Note that going prone has specific game mechanics associated, but anything else like crouching, bending over, going on tip toes, require a ruling from the DM.

Comment: I generally agree that this answer is _probably_ the correct one, but in terms of RPG.SE standards it would be stronger if it cited the rules for support.